# How do I write to the VB6 immediate window from C++ based COM object?

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, com, vb6

I have developed a C++ based COM object to use it in a VB6 application. Now I need to add some logging to catch some of the bugs. I discovered from the answer to ['How to debug COM object in Visual Studio 6.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370250/how-to-debug-com-object-in-visual-studio-6-0-that-is-created-in-an-asp-page) question that I can use the `OutputDebugString` function. But is it possible to write to the VB6 immediate window somehow?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than attempting to write to the immediate window, it would be generally more useful to use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) from Sysinternals (now part of Microsoft technet):

> DebugView is an application that lets you monitor debug output on your
>   local system, or any computer on the network that you can reach via
>   TCP/IP. It is capable of displaying both kernel-mode and Win32 debug
>   output, so you don't need a debugger to catch the debug output your
>   applications or device drivers generate, nor do you need to modify
>   your applications or drivers to use non-standard debug output APIs.

You can use this during development and also in production.

> Under Windows 2000, XP, Server 2003 and Vista DebugView will capture:
>
> - Win32 OutputDebugString
> - Kernel-mode DbgPrint
> - All kernel-mode variants of DbgPrint implemented in Windows XP and
>     Server 2003

Comment: +1. Life is even better if you can view the VB6 and C++ log messages together in DebugView. Change the VB6 to log with `OutputDebugString` not `Debug.Print`. Just copy the routine DebugOutput from [this](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/11/17/executing-debuggables.aspx) excellent Karl Peterson article

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can write direct to it but you can use a COM event that just contains a debug.print call.