# Is it possible to write to the VBA immediate window from a C# COM interop object?

Tags: c#, vba, com, interop

I have written a C# COM object to be consumed by MSAccess. It's working very well for my purposes, but I'd like to do a version check when a new object is created, and notify the VBA programmer that a new version is available, via the immediate window.

Is this possible? I have tried Debug.Print and Console.WriteLine but neither works.

I have found several posts (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384976/how-do-i-write-to-the-vb6-immediate-window-from-c-based-com-object)) that ask the question, but don't really provide an answer.

Comment: Neither would work.  DefaultTraceListener.Write/Line() ought to have a shot at it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the docs for DefaultTraceListener and saw that it gets added to Debug.Listeners and Trace.Listeners so I tried iterating through both and calling WriteLine. The output ends up going to VS's output window. Any way to "register" VBA as a listener?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible... but not pretty or dependable.

Here is a VBA sub I just wrote after doing research and experimenting that does what you want. Offered essentially as a proof of concept.

```
Sub ImmediateWindowSendKeys(keys As String)
    set w = Application.VBE.windows("Immediate")
    w.SetFocus
    SendKeys keys
    w.Visible = True
End Sub
```

I assume you can convert this into the language you want, or even call this sub from C#. The primary issue with this method is that it does not work if you are stepping through code, have set a break point anywhere in the current processing, or generate a pop-up alert (This is a limitation of send keys). It does, however, work if ran with F5 or from the immediate window.

I'll try to figure out a way to access the contents of the window, but right now this is the best I can offer.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, this should be equally useless. However, I have only just started dabbling in this sort of thing so it's a kind of play. This will add comments to the end of the current module.

```
Sub AddCommentsToEndOfModule()
    Set cm = Application.vbe.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule
    cm.InsertLines cm.CountOfLines + 1, "'Dear Developer " & vbCrLf & "'Hi" & vbCrLf & "'Sincerely," & vbCrLf & "'Me"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Daniel. If I exhaust all other possibilities maybe I will go this route. The problem is that it requires a reference to the Access application, which I can't get without explicitly passing it (unless there's some hackish way of getting it, which is possible). So I'm not sure how I could do this on object creation, since VBA doesn't allow parameters in a New statement. Anyway +1 for the idea; it may be useful-- thank you!

Comment: True enough. I had a sudden forgetfulness about what exactly "consume" meant. I'm going to add another possible method of getting a message to the developer that is probably equally as helpful.

Comment: While this may work, as @DanielCook points out, it's really _really_ fragile. It also doesn't take into account the fact that the user may be in the middle of using the immediate window - and thus you may be appending to half-written commands/etc... While this may work as a last resort, please avoid it if you can. That said, if nothing better comes along, I'll +1 for lateral thinking